# Meaning of "Early days I know but may help."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading an email from my client about the changes that he wants me to make.

In the end, there is a sentence:

> Early days I know but may help.

Can someone explain the meaning of this sentence?

"Early days I know" means he already knew it earlier? "But may help"?

Comment: It may mean that he knows that you are in early days of the (project? task?), and that whatever he has written in the email may help you in achieving that (project? task?). More context of the email would be helpful in ascertaining what he meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I know these are early days" i.e. the project is new, young.

"may help" simply means "this may help".

Answer (score 5):

Your client has used a highly condensed form of idiomatic expression to explain why he is sending such comments at this time.

In fully expanded form, he might have said:

> I am aware that this project is not far advanced and that others might wait longer before suggesting changes; but if these issues are dealt with now, it could be very beneficial in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

*Early days* is a British idiom meaning "it’s too soon to make a judgment" about something.
So I think he means it’s too soon to judge on your project but it may help.