# I am familiar with the expression "early days" - but what does "early doors" mean?

Tags: idioms

I saw this answer regarding "early days" in a related question, [Meaning of "Early days I know but may help."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91514/meaning-of-early-days-i-know-but-may-help):

> Early days is a British idiom meaning "it’s too soon to make a judgment" about something.

Why, then, do people say "early doors"?

How can a door be early?

Comment: Who said "early doors"? Where did you see or hear it?

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+early+doors%2Cthe+early+customers%2Cthe+early+patrons&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20early%20doors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20early%20customers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20early%20patrons%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20early%20doors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20early%20customers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20early%20patrons%3B%2Cc0), idiomatic ***the early doors*** displaced ***early patrons*** back in the music-hall 1920s. But that's ancient history - today they're all just ***early customers***.

Comment: (Except the collocation had a bit of a revival because of a British sitcom a couple of decades ago.)

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - I hear it all the time on British TV and radio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Early doors" in British English has a rather different meaning from "early days" in the linked question. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/early_doors) has

> **early doors**
> *informal British*
> Early on, especially in a game or contest.
> *you should try to wind up their star player early doors*
>
> Origin
> Apparently originally with reference to admission to a music hall some time before the start of the performance.

The phrase is also used to refer to customers of a pub who get there right on opening time. There was a British TV sitcom called **Early Doors** about which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Doors) says:

> Etymology of show's title
>
> The title is a British slang phrase meaning those who arrive earlier than is customary, and was often associated with pub customers who wait for or arrive soon after evening opening, around 5:30 pm. Until the law was changed in 1988, pubs in England closed in the afternoon. Most are now open all day. It is also widely heard in British football circles, and was resuscitated in comments about football. The phrase originates in the practice of British theatres from around 1870 of allowing customers who paid a little extra to enter the theatre early and choose their own seats to beat the rush just before the performance started.

Comment: I have heard (UK) 'early doors' used in meetings to signify that they will finish earlier than scheduled, and that in general it means 'somewhat earlier than expected'. Some usage blogs suggest it is mainly used in connection with football ('soccer') and mainly in the North of England, but I think it has escaped those confines and is out in the wild.

Answer (score -1):

Early doors is to leave early BEFORE the doors close.
In the pub "Another one? No thanks, early doors, out tomorrow morning"
NOT FOR BEING EARLY, as some of the 12 year olds would let you believe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).